# PHP strpos() crashing script

Tags: php, strpos

I have a PHP script that looks for links on a page that it downloads with CURL_MULTI functions. The downloading is fine and I get the data, but my script randomly crashes when I encounter a page that has the url listed as a nonlink. This is the code:

```
$fishnof = strpos($nofresult, $supshorturl, 0);
$return[0] = ''; $return[1] = ''; // always good to cleanset

// Make sure we grabbed a link instead of a text url(no href)
if ($fishnof !== false) {
    $linkcheck = rev_strpos($nofresult,'href',$fishnof);
    $endthis = false;
    while($endthis !== true) {
        if($linkcheck > ($fishnof - 25)){ // 19 accounts for href="https://blog. 25 just in case
            $endthis = true;
            break;
        }
        $lastfishnof = $fishnof;
        $fishnof = strpos($nofresult,$supshorturl,$fishnof+1);
        if($fishnof === false){$fishnof = $lastfishnof;$linkcheck = rev_strpos($nofresult,'href',$fishnof);$endthis = true;break;}// This is the last occurance of our URL on this page
        if($linkcheck > $fishnof){$linkcheck = rev_strpos($nofresult,'href',$fishnof);$endthis = true;break;} // We went around past the end of the string(probably don't need this)      
        $linkcheck = rev_strpos($nofresult,'href',$fishnof);
    }
    if($linkcheck < ($fishnof - 25)){ // 19 accounts for href="https://blog. 25 just in case
        $return[0] = 'Non-link.';
        $return[1] = '-';
        $nofresult = NULL; // Clean up our memory
        unset($nofresult); // Clean up our memory
        return $return;
    }
}
```

This is the custom rev_strpos, which just does a reverse `strpos()`:

```
// Does a reverse stripos()
function rev_strpos(&$haystack, $needle, $foffset = 0){
    $length = strlen($haystack);
    $offset = $length - $foffset - 1;
    $pos = strpos(strrev($haystack), strrev($needle), $offset);
    return ($pos === false)?false:( $length - $pos - strlen($needle) );
}
```

so if:

```
$nofresult = '
Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.
Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.
Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.
google.com Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.
Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.
Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a> Some text.Some text.
Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.';
```

and

```
$supshorturl = "google.com";
```

This should find the position of the second occurance of google.com, where it is inside of a HTML href tag. The problem is that it does not report any error before the crash, my error settings:

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
set_error_handler('handle_errors');
```

My `handle_errors()` function logs all errors in a file. However no errors are reported before the script crashes. Also my curl_multi processes many URLs, and sometimes it will crash on a certain URL and and other times it crashes on another URL... I am ready to pull out my hair because this seems like such an easy deal... but here I am. Another point of notice is if I remove the while loop then no crash, also if the page has the url in a href tag first then it doesn't crash. Please help me figure this thing out. Thanks a million!

Comment: What about using regex to get the urls?

Comment: I need the position of the location of that URL on the page, not the URL itself.

Comment: And the problem is? You can perfectly use a callback to do whatever you want with the returned data.

Comment: Please answer the question with code that would accomplish the above using regex and I will try it

Comment: [strrpos](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) ?

Comment: There are tons of examples on google, here's one : http://www.desilva.biz/php/xtracturl.html

Comment: That example does not return the position of that match but only whether it found it or not, again I NEED the position of where that URL is located.

Comment: Once again, you just need to use a callback to determine the position of the url with a `$flag`. Furthermore, `preg_match` already does that for you when it pushes the matches found into an array, and the callback function is unecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're making it harder than it needs to be.  If `rev_strpos` is only needed to return the last instance of your search string, *and if you aren't worried about case*, use `strripos` instead.

From the PHP docs...

> [strripos — Find position of last occurrence of a case-insensitive string in a string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strripos.php)
>
> **Description**
>
> ```
> int strripos ( string $haystack , string $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )
> ```
>
> Find position of last occurrence of a string in a string. Unlike strrpos(), strripos() is case-insensitive.

If you need it to be case-sensitive, or just want to use your own function for some reason, the problem is in how you are calculating the offset.  Specifically in these 2 lines:

```
$offset = $length - $foffset - 1;
$pos = strpos(strrev($haystack), strrev($needle), $offset);
```

Using your sample "Some text..." and searching for "google.com", if we don't specify an offset it calculates the offset as length (500 chars) - offset (0 chars) - 1.  Then you use strpos on a 500-char length string starting at offset character 499.  You're never going to find anything that way.

Since you are reversing your haystack and also your needle, you need to "reverse" your offset.  Change the line to:

```
$pos = strpos(strrev($haystack), strrev($needle), $length - $offset);
```

(Actually, you should change your prior line to calculate the $offset where you want it to be, but you get the point...)

***UPDATE:***

Further to the recommendations about using Regex, it's really trivial to get locations:

```
function getOffsets( $url, $baseRegex, $text ){
    $results = array();
    $regex= str_replace( '%URL%', $url, $baseRegex );
    preg_match_all( $regex, $text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );

    foreach ( $matches[0] as $match )
        array_push( $results, ($match[1] + strpos( $match[0], $url )) );

    return $results;
}

$linkRegex = '/<a[^>]*href="[^"]*%URL%[^"]*"[^>]*>/i';
$linkLocations = getOffsets( $url, $linkRegex, $text );
//Array
//(
//    [0] => 395
//)

$anyRegex = '/%URL%/i';
$allLocations = getOffsets( $url, $anyRegex, $text );
$nonlinkLocations = array_diff( $allLocations, $linkLocations );  //all non-links
//Array
//(
//    [0] => 188
//)
```

This really should be preferable to the `rev_strpos` & `while` loop gimmicks.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this question, but your answers are not correct on both counts. The function that you recommend 'finds the last occurrence of string'. I need it to find a sting in reverse of the offset.

The offset calculation is not correct either. Since you are searching in reverse and the offset given is 0, then we are trying to search past the beginning of a sting. The math is correct.

Comment: @Serj My apologies, I may not understand your "find a string in reverse of the offset" desire.  However, I'm quite certain that your math is incorrect.  If you use your example values, you search for a 10-character needle in a 500-character haystack but you start at offset 499.  `strpos` is searching strings that have been reversed, but it is not searching backwards, so it won't find anything when it starts at the end of the string.  Using `strripos` (or the modified `rev_strpos` that I suggested) do find 'google.com' at offset 395, which is exactly where it is.

Comment: (continued)  If you are looking for the distance from the end of the "needle" text to your offset, that is easy enough to calculate from once you have found the starting position.

Comment: using the function as is:
strrev() will do this:
data: ' moc.elgoog .txet emoS'
searching for: 'moc.elgoog'
if we give an offset of 21 and we want to find a string backwards, strpos will find it since 22-21-1 = 0 and strpos will find it. You would not want to send an offset of 0 to this function, because then you are asking it to search backwards from position 0. Trust me the math is correct. I have re-verified it many times with multiple sources.

Comment: @Serj are you trying to do anything with the return value before you verify it's not null?  In your sample code, you can exit your `while` loop at the condition `if($linkcheck > ($fishnof - 25)`, but you only return a value `if($linkcheck < ($fishnof - 25))`.  If this is the full code of that function, you could be exiting your while loop and returning a null value.

Comment: Yeah I didn't include the unnecessary code that deals with a correctly found href URL.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is this parse error

```
$nofresult = "
Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.
Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.
Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.
google.com Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.
Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.
Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a> Some text.Some text.
Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.";
```

... it should be

```
$nofresult = "
Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.
Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.
Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.
google.com Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.
Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.
Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.
<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Google</a> Some text.Some text.
Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.";
```

Comment: $nofresult is actually data that I downloaded with multi_curl The text it contains is not set by me.

Comment: @SerjSagan: That's the biggest problem of askers. They can't simulate every behavior without making parse error ;)